# c++ delete statement for pointer of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

suppose I have some classes

```
class word{
public:
    string term;
    word(){}
    word(string s){term = s;}
};

class cont{
public:
    word** terms;
    cont(){};
    cont(int n){terms = new word*[n];}
};
```

suppose now I initialize a cont and its attribute terms like this

```
cont c(5);
c.terms[0] = new word("a");
c.terms[1] = new word("b");
c.terms[2] = new word("c");
```

how should I delete the elements of this array? one by one? all at once? I didn't get how the delete/delete[] syntax works for pointer of pointers.

Comment: You shouldn't use raw pointers at all. Besides that, keep balance for every `new` apply a `delete`, same for `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: "You shouldn't use raw pointers at all" Is that just because something like `arr[i]` is easier to type and understand than `*(arr + i)`?

Answer (score 1):

Delete objects first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    delete c.terms[i];
}
```

Delete the array in the end:

```
delete[] c.terms;
```

But yes, this is certainly a very basic question that has been asked and elaborated many times.